# equals works different in java 6 and java 7

Tags: java

equals vs == in java 6 and java 7:

Guys unfortunatly I don't have an example because I helping some students at school and sometime they use this structure in java 7 and works even with some objects, I just want to know if there is some diference between java 6 and 7 about this and I know that we shoud use aways equals when we use string.

I've tested string and objects with equals but I realized that sometimes there is no problem using == instead equals in java 7, is there any diferences the way java 6 and 7 handle that?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Without details, this question is too vague to answer.

Comment: I kind of doubt there's a huge difference.

Comment: You should never use "==" as a comparison of equality in content of strings.

Comment: your question needs an SSCCE [http://www.sscce.org/]

Comment: I know that i should'nt use "==" the problem é because i help new students in a course and some time they use it and works, because this I have no examples

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty sure you compared Strings and String literals, generally

```
Object o = new Object();
Object o2 = new Object();
o == o2  -> False as it compares object identity 
o.equals(o2) -> False because default implementation of equals compares identities.


String a = new String("a1");
String b = new String ("a1");
String c = "a1";
String d = "a1"; 

a == b -> False as it compares object identity 
a.equals(b) -> True as String ovverrides the method and it compares String's content
c == d -> True because these are declared as string literals and have the same identity (interned Strings are stored in memory only once to reduce memory usage)
c.equals(d) -> True because content of strings is the same.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of cases where == might work. For example certain Integer and String values share a common cache and if the values you are comparing all come from that cache then you will get a match.

For example:

```
 Integer.valueOf(1) == Integer.valueOf(1)
```

is true but

```
 new Integer(1) == new Integer(1)
```

is false.

In general except in very controlled situations you should never use == for comparison, it's just not worth the risk.